# Predict interface names starting from ubuntu 15.10

Tags: bash, networking, interface, ubuntu-15.10

As mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689070/network-interface-name-changes-after-update-to-15-10-udev-changes) since Ubutnu 15.10 there are some different naming schemes for network interfaces supported:

- Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided index numbers for on-board
  devices (example: eno1)
- Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided PCI Express hotplug slot
  index numbers (example: ens1)
- Names incorporating physical/geographical location of the
  connector of the hardware (example: enp2s0)
- Names incorporating the interfaces's MAC address (example:
  enx78e7d1ea46da)
- Classic, unpredictable kernel-native ethX naming (example: eth0) -
  depreciated

I am writing a script that takes interface name with grep:

```
if_name=$(ls /sys/class/net | grep "en")
```

and then changes it to **eth**. I've tested script on a few machines and it was fine, but is there a chance that interface name now can start from another letters and my command above won't work? And if so, are there any better alternatives?

Comment: Yes there is a better way than doing some bash script for it. Have a look at the why/how this was done [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/), and especially the section "I don't like this, how do I disable this?"

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i am doing in my script, but before that, i need to invoke current interface name and current MAC address, that belongs to its name.

Comment: Yes, and that is why you _do not want to to that in a script_, but rather _automatically at system startup_ , following the pointers in "I don't like this, how do I disable this?" link I provided. Otherwise you have a chicken and egg problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c#L20) that two character prefixes based on the type of interface:

```
 *   en -- Ethernet
 *   sl -- serial line IP (slip)
 *   wl -- wlan
 *   ww -- wwan
```

Also, the best way to find out you primary interface name:

```
route |grep default |awk  ' {print $8} '
```